# objective-c is assigning a different object type to an object terribly wrong?What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: objective-c

Both DriverView and NetDriverView are a subclass of UIView.

```
- (NetDriverView *)netDriver {
if (!_netDriver) {
    _netDriver = [NetDriverView netDriverView];
    _netDriver.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, WIDTH - 10, 72);
}
return _netDriver;
}

- (DriverView *)driverView {
if (!_driverView) {

    if([APPConfig carType] == Taxi){
        _driverView = [DriverView driverView];
        _driverView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, WIDTH - 10, 130);

        _driverView.hiddenShare = YES;
        _driverView.showAll = YES;


    } else {
        _driverView = self.netDriver;
    }
}
return _driverView;
```

}

And in my viewDidLoad(), I just do

```
[self.view addSubview: self.driverView];
```

It works well, but it gets a warning at incompatible pointer assigning at this line

```
_driverView = self.netDriver;
```

how should i get rid of this warning? Is this a wrong way to do? what would be potential dangers of doing this?

Doing this has an advantage that i could save lines of code about checking the carType and differentiating the driverView and the netDriverView.

Comment: Yeah because a NetDriverView is not a subclass of DriverView. Either make it a subclass or declare _driverView as UIView.

Comment: One is a bicycle, the other a car. Both are vehicles and fine if you want to break or steer but what happens when you try to open the doors of a bicycle or pedal a car?

Comment: @HAS, If I declare _driverView as UIView, I won't access the attributes of the driverView. Now I make NetDriverView a subclass of DriverView. But I customize something in DriverView's awakeFromNib method, which I don't want apply to the NetDriverView. But I also need to call the method [super awakeFromNib] in netDriverView, otherwise the compiler will give me a warning Method possibly Missing  a [super awakeFromNib] call.

Comment: Then what you want and need is a protocol ;)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, most of the methods are the same. And before I open the doors, I will make sure that the object is a car. If I pedal, I will make sure that it's a bicycle. There is only one method that I should do such a check thing.

Comment: You can't simply assign netDriver to driverView if these 2 are instances of different parent classes and that's why xcode is showing a warning.